# How to fill TableColumns with the User object information?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

I have a TableView and inside there are TableColumns([Screenshot of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHxVk.jpg))

The method receives an ArrayList of Users(potentialFriends). The object User consists of the full name, email, hobby, major and the matching score. I want to fill the Table with the information of every User object in the ArrayList. How is it done exactly? I have done some research, but nothing seems to work.
Here is a piece of code, if it helps:

```
public class AlgorithmController {

@FXML
private TableView<User> table;
@FXML
private TableColumn<User,String> nameCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<User,String> majorCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<User,String> mailCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<User,String> hobbyCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<User,String> scoreCol;
private User user;
private ArrayList<User> potentialFriends;


public void initialize(){
    DatabaseStack database = new DatabaseStack();
    MatchingAlgorithm testAlg = new MatchingAlgorithm(database.getDatabase());
    user = Mediator.getInstance().getUser();
    potentialFriends = testAlg.findAFriendAlgorithm(user,0,database.getDatabase().size());

}}
```

Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: Did you bind (inject) correctly your `TableColumn` between your `Controller` and the `FXML` file ?

Comment: @BoHalim Yea, I just have no idea how to actually fill columns with the information.

Answer (score 0):

Set cellValueFactory for each column.
For instance,

```
nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User,String>("Specify nameCol variable name the same as in User class"));
```

Then add the array list.

```
table.setItems(potentialFriends);
```

If the adding array list doesn't work, try using an `ObservableList` instead of an `ArrayList`.

Comment: It should be `table.getItems().setAll(potentialFriends)`, since `potentialFriends` is not an `ObservableList`. Look at the [Javadocs for `PropertyValueFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) to understand how the constructor parameter is used (it is not necessarily the "variable name").

Comment: I am getting an error: "WARNING: Can not retrieve property 'Ethan White' in PropertyValueFactory: javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory@3a5bb0a1 with provided class type: class FindAFriend.User
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read from unreadable property Ethan White". What can be wrong? I have done exactly what you said.

Comment: @DmytroMarych I got this error and realized my bean had default access modifiers instead of public!!   gosh that was annoying and so obvious I never thought to look there for 2 hours ha!